# more efficient approximate String matching with MongoDB

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, string-matching, similarity

I have this relatively large (almost 130000 documents) MongoDB collection of names, that contains a lot of duplicates due to OCR Noise and I'm trying to group these duplicates together using approximate String matching.
I've Implemented this in Java using the [Simmetrics library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) like so:

```
DBCursor persons = coll.find(query).addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
        try{
            while(persons.hasNext()){
                DBObject p = persons.next();

                DBObject personName = (DBObject) p.get("person");
                String n1 = personName.get("Name").toString();
                System.out.println("\n"+ personName + ":");

                DBCursor aliases = coll.find(query).addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
                try{
                    while(aliases.hasNext()){
                        DBObject a = aliases.next();    

                        DBObject aliasName = (DBObject) a.get("person");                            
                        String n2 = aliasName.get("Name").toString();

                        float simLev = new Levenshtein().getSimilarity(n1, n2);

                        if (simLev >= 0.65){
                        System.out.println("    "+ aliasName + ", Sim: " + simLev);
                        }
                    }
                } finally{
                    aliases.close();
                }

            }
        } finally{
            persons.close();
        }
```

So I'm comparing every document with every document using two cursors and (for testing purposes atm) am only printing out matches with a 65% or higher similarity (using Levenshtein distance as an example).
Example output for 1 name:

```
{ "Name" : "Baldaino, Manene M."}:
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Manene M."}, Sim: 1.0
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene C4."}, Sim: 0.8095238
    { "Name" : "Baldaino Marlene M"}, Sim: 0.78947365
    { "Name" : "BaldainD, Marlene M."}, Sim: 0.85
    { "Name" : "Baldaino Madene M."}, Sim: 0.8947368
    { "Name" : "Baidaino, Marlene M"}, Sim: 0.78947365
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene M. 0C"}, Sim: 0.7826087
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene M. (0"}, Sim: 0.7826087
    { "Name" : "8aldaino, Marlene M,"}, Sim: 0.8
    { "Name" : "Baldaino Madene"}, Sim: 0.7368421
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene 00"}, Sim: 0.8
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene hi."}, Sim: 0.8095238
    { "Name" : "BaWaino, Marlene M."}, Sim: 0.78947365
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene M. (3i"}, Sim: 0.75
    { "Name" : "Bedainc, Marlene M."}, Sim: 0.7368421
    { "Name" : "Baldaino, Marlene M. cfl"}, Sim: 0.75
```

this Implementation isn't very efficient though, running it on the whole Collection would I think take at least 40 hours on my PC.

Does anyone know how I could get a better performance?
I've read about using [ElasticSearch with Mongo Connector](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/95839709598/how-to-perform-fuzzy-matching-with-mongo-connector), but would prefer not having to learn to use a new tool just for this.

Comment: Well you can always use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operations. But your parameters are not really made clear. Advanced "word stemming" is really the domain of "search engines" and not "databases" if that is the only way you can express this.

Comment: @NeilLunn, how would I use $regex for this purpose? And should I try using a "search engine" then?

Comment: Well the main point would be to "narrow down" in the query selection. As in a basic example: `^Bal`. But that is very basic since your "similarity rules " are not specifically defined here. MongoDB otherwise supports "very basic" text search functionality. That is not dissimilar to other database engines. "Search Engines" on the other hand offer a lot more. So it is a choice for you to either use the capabilities from the services you have available or to otherwise "code" to inspect the response on the client. Your choice.

Comment: alright, is there a search engine you can recommend, that offers "Fuzzy" String matching metrics?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very fast algorithm for doing String similarity against a big set of Entries. Check Simstring[1]. This is highly optimised way to do cosine, jaccard and dice string similarities.
The author claimed he could query Google Web1T unigrams (13,588,391 strings) that have cosine similarity ≧0.7 in 1.10 [ms] per query (on Intel Xeon 5140 2.33 GHz CPU).

First it builds a map of ngrams, then given a query it calcualtes the minimum set of ngram matches that it should have to be a match.

I've used it to match millions of Freebase Names against a set of entity names with other millions of entries.

I worked in an implementation on Scala recently [2]. But you can also use Chokkan implementation( Need to compile from c++ and then generate the swig class for Java).

If you dump the strings out from mongo, and use this data structure you can definitely compute the approximate string matches very fast.

[1] http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/

[2] https://github.com/dav009/FuzzyDict

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, never used swig before though,

Comment: Try the scala project ( https://github.com/dav009/FuzzyDict )you dont need to deal with any wrapper in c++.

Answer (score 0):

I think can load this request result in memory (you can use Go of ram) with "name" and "id" it'll avoid the second cursor in the loop. It'll increase performance.

```
List<NameID> nameIds = new List<NameID>(100000);
    DBCursor persons = coll.find(query).addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
        try{
            while(persons.hasNext()){
                    DBObject p = persons.next();
                  nameIds.add(new NameId((DBObject) p.get("person"),(DBObject) p.get("ID"))
         }
    } } finally{
            persons.close();
        } }
```

After loop the list in your algorithm.

Comment: Next optimization is that your algorithm match A-B and after B-A, maybe you can avoid the second matching operation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are only looking at the person.Name subfield in the document, 
but you are loading the entire document from the database - wasting RAM and bandwidth.

Doing this:

```
find(query).projection(new Document("person.Name", 1))
```

should speed things up a bit.